# Java - mouse click using coords within an active window

Tags: java, awtrobot

After googling for a while I found nothing helpful and I really need an advice.

I'm making a simple java bot for an online game and I need to simulate mouse clicks at certain constant coordinates. The game runs in a windowed mode which is much smaller than desktop resolution and the game client's location on the screen is not constant.

How can I make clicks at predefined coordinates which are relative to the running application's window? I don't see how I can use Java robot class here since it uses screen coordinates.
I'm even thinking of making an AHK script which can easily perform my task and calling it from java program each time I need to make a mouse click..

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Robot](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) class. You can do pretty much everything with Robot class as simulation.

```
Robot bot = new Robot();
bot.mouseMove(x, y);    
bot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
bot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
```

Comment: Are you sure you read my whole post and not only it's topic? I don't see how robot class can use client coordinates (not screen coordinates).

Comment: @Conrad Is your client application developed using Java? If yes, then you CAN use robot class. You have to calculate x,y depending on your need.